# Mean of log t-student distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Assume that $x$ is a  t-student random varaible as $p({\bf{x}}) = T({\boldsymbol{\mu }},{\bf{\Sigma }},\nu )$ with mean ${\boldsymbol{\mu }}$, covaraince matrix ${\bf{\Sigma }}$ and degree of freedom $\nu $. I want to compute  the mean of ${\bf{y}} = \exp({\bf{x}})$. But as I know there no closed form formula for this. I want to appaximte its mean as

$E[{\bf{y}}] =E[\exp({\bf{x}})] \approx \exp({\boldsymbol{\mu }})$

But I do not know what $\exp({\boldsymbol{\mu }})$ represents. Is it the median of $\bf y$?

Any hint?

Comment: How would you define the median of a multidimensional random variable?

Answer (score 1):

Since $x$ has power-law tails, $\exp x$ has infinite mean. (It's not even defined if $x$ is multivariate.)

Comment: Thanks. How about the median or mode of $\bf y$? Are they defined?

Comment: @user51780 Only the univariate case is defined. The mean is $\exp\mu$, but the mode's somewhere slightly different, because maximizing $p(\ln y)/y$ isn't the same as maximizing $p(\ln y)$.

Comment: I got a bit confused! Here, I think you are saying the median. Am I correct?

Comment: @user51780 Sorry, yes.